# How to persist configuration changes accross restart with LXD containers?

Tags: networking, server, lxc, lxd

I am experimenting with LXD, but I'm stuck with a seamingly simple problem: I can't make my bridge config persistent.

The host server has a birdge `br0`. By default, lxd managed containers will use `lxcbr0` and be on another network.

What I want is a container that will get its IP from my main DHCP server, and share the same network as the rest of my servers.

I managed to do so using this stanza:

```
lxc config set mycontainer raw.lxc 'lxc.network.link = br0'
```

This seems to work, but every now and then, the configuration gets lost, and the container falls back onto lxcbr0 !

- So, is this the right way to get my container to use br0 ?
- And what is the way to make this persistent for real ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this using a profile.

```
lxc config profile edit bridge
```

Then in the editor:

```
name: bridge
config: {}
devices:
    eth0:
        nictype: bridged
        parent: br0
        type: nic
```

And when creating a guest/container, specify the profile

```
lxc launch ubuntu GUESTNAME -p bridge
```

Not sure, but assume you can apply the profile to existing guests/containers as well. Have not tried it.

**EDIT:**
From lxd 0.18 `profile` is part of main commands:

`lxc profile edit bridge`

Comment: thanks for the tip, this seems to be what I was looking for. Notice the syntax has evolved a bit (LXD 0.18) to 'lxc profile edit bridge' (no more config keyword).