# Where to configure lxd containers?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I installed LXD and created a few containers and while reading about various configurations (specifically about [how to run unprivileged containers as root](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/#creating-unprivileged-containers-as-root)), I saw that the configuration files referenced in the various pages are

- multiple (`/etc/lxc/default.conf`, `/var/lib/lxc/<container>/default`, ...)
- and for the most part do not exist on mu Ubuntu 15.10.

It looks like the `lxc` command is the actual way to go, for instance

```
# lxc profile show test1
name: test1
config: {}
description: ""
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br2
    type: nic
```

I do not understand how information of the kind

> Append to [one of the config files mentioned above]
>
> ```
> lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536
> lxc.id_map = g 0 100000 65536
> ```

fits into the `lxc` command (if at all):

- should I be editing the configuration via `lxc profile edit test1` - in which case where (to take the example above) would `lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536` go in?
- or [use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650546/how-to-persist-configuration-changes-accross-restart-with-lxd-containers) something like `lxc config set test1 raw.lxc 'lxc.id_map = u 0 100000 65536'`? (when tested, it does not appear in the profile after execution)
- or something else?

Comment: I used your second method mentioned (`lxc config set container raw.lxc`) and it showed up in my configuration afterwards when I ran `lxc config show --expanded container`. I am guessing (have not verified) that you can  use the first method by adding under `container:` the line `raw.lxc: lxc.id_map = u 0 100000`